# BroadcastReceiver does not receive Broadcast from IntentService

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentservice

I'm trying to send a broadcast from an IntentService to the activity that started it, this is how i register the Receiver in the activity:

```
private BroadcastReceiver mInitializer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ....
    mInitializer = new InitializationReceiver();
    IntentFilter initializer = new IntentFilter();
    initializer.addAction(IntentConstants.Tasks.INITIALIZE);
    initializer.addAction(IntentConstants.Initialization.INITIALIZE_IS_FIRST_START);
    initializer.addAction("test");
    registerReceiver(mInitializer, initializer);
    ....
}

private class InitializationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private InitializationReceiver() {
        if(D) Log.d(TAG, "Instantiated InitializationReceiver");
    }
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(D) Log.d(TAG, "Received broadcast, intentAction: "+intent.getAction());
        if(intent.getAction().equals(IntentConstants.Tasks.INITIALIZE)) {
            if(D) Log.d(TAG, "Received Initialize Intent");
        }
        if(intent.getAction().equals(IntentConstants.Initialization.INITIALIZE_IS_FIRST_START)) {
            if(D) Log.d(TAG, "Received First Start Intent");
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how i send the broadcast from the IntentService:

```
if(D) Log.d(TAG, "Got here");
Intent testIntent = new Intent("test");
sendBroadcast(testIntent);
```

- The service is created cause "Got here" gets logged,
- the BroadcastReceiver is initialized before the service being created and
- the activity is visible when the broadcast is sent.
- the broadcast is not received, cause "Received broadcast..." is never logged

What could cause this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should `register` and `unregister` your receivers in `onResume()` and in `onPause()` respectively. Cause if you only register it in `onCreate()` and unregister in `onPause()`, then the next time the activity is brought to the foreground, `onCreate()` will not be called again and then it will not register the receiver again. But `onResume()` is always called on the activity being displayed.

```
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ....
    registerReceiver(myBroadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
}

public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    ...
    unregisterReceiver(myBroadcastReceiver);
}
```

Comment: You were right, Facebook login was causing the activity to Stop, then in the onStop i was unregistering the Receiver. after that it was no more registered.